# Bootstrap 4 always collapsing div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get 2 divs side by side. This should be straight forward but my divs are always collapsing. I can expand the screen as much as I like but they stay collapsed.  I have done this before and this should work.  Can someone check my sanity pls.
Using BS 4.4.1

```
<row class="justify-content-center">            
        <div class="col-5" style="background-color:red">    
            <p>Select your Wi-Fi Network</p>    
        </div>    
        <div class="col-5" style="background-color:blue">
            <p>Select your Wi-Fi Network</p>    
        </div>       
</row>
```

Comment: Are you getting same result as on this link? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBUST4XKXWHT . please clarify what is your requirement?

Comment: Yes exactly that - although the bottom answer seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use div class = "row" instead of row.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-5" style="background-color:red">
            <p>Select your Wi-Fi Network</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5" style="background-color:blue">
            <p>Select your Wi-Fi Network</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use container class and then you should use row and col accordingly to make responsive div.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red">
     <p>Select your Wi-Fi Network</p> 
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue">
            <p>Select your Wi-Fi Network</p>    
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```